# JS Hangman - Working with multi-word answers within the array

Tags: javascript

The only "solution" I've found is to remove spaces between names in the array, so "bon jovi" becomes "bonjovi", etc.  I cannot find any solutions to deal with spaces within the array, aside from displaying the "*".  I'm re-checking to see if anyone has solutions to deal with the code dealing successfully with multi-word answers within the array - or if there even is one.  Again, any help would be appreciated.

Here is both HTML and JS:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
  <title>Hangman</title>

  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="assets/css/style.css">

</head>
<body>

  <header>
    <img src="assets/images/background.png" class="header-img" alt="80's picture">
  </header>

  <div class="container">
    <h3>Press any key to get started!</h3>
    <div class="row">        
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="game">         
          <p><span id="win-counter">Wins: </span></p>
          <p><span id="loss-counter">Losses: </span></p>
          <p><span id="wrong-guesses">Wrong Guesses: </span></p>
          <p><span id="guesses-left">Guesses Remaining: </span></p>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="col-md-5">
        <div class="play">
          <h3>Guess the singer or band!</h3>
          <h3><span id="wordToGuess">_ _ _ _ _ _ _</span></h3>
          <br>
          <p id="disclosure">" * " denotes blank space(s)</p>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="empty-div"></div>
    </div>
  </div>  


 <script>

// GLOBAL VARIABLES
// =======================================================

// Array of word options
var bands = ["bangles", "pat benatar", "bon jovi", "david bowie", "chicago", "phil collins", "culture club", "duran duran", "eurythmics", "fleetwood mac", "foreigner", "genesis", "heart", "whitney houston", "billy idol", "janet jackson", "michael jackson", "billy joel", "elton john", "journey", "cyndi lauper", "kenny loggins", "madonna", "richard marx", "george michael", "motley crue", "pet shop boys", "poison", "prince", "reo speedwagon", "lionel richie", "rod stewart", "styx", "tina turner", "thompson twins", "van halen", "wham"]

// Stores Computer-selected word
var selectedWord = "";

// Array of individual letters to each word
var lettersInWord = [];

// Number of blanks based on solution (selectedWord)
var numBlanks = 0;

// Array to hold mix of blank and solved letters (ex: 'n, _ _, n, _').
var blanksAndSuccesses = [];

// Stores all wrong guesses
var wrongGuesses = [];

// Holds the letters guessed
var letterGuessed = "";

// Game counters
var winCounter = 0;
var lossCounter = 0;
var numGuesses = 15;

// FUNCTIONS
// =======================================================

// startGame() will start and restart game
function startGame() {

  // Reset guesses back to 15
  numGuesses = 15;

  // Reset the "guess and success" array at each round
  blanksAndSuccesses = [];

  // Reset wrong guesses from previous round
  wrongGuesses = [];

  // Solution chosen randomly from bands
  selectedWord = bands[Math.floor(Math.random() * bands.length)];

  // Breaks solution word into individual letters
  lettersInWord = selectedWord.split("");

  // Counts the number of letters in the word
  numBlanks = lettersInWord.length;

  // Print solution in console (for testing)
  console.log(selectedWord);

  // Fill "blanksAndSuccesses" list with appropriate number of blanks, based on number of letters in solution word
  for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {
    if (lettersInWord[i] === " ") {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("*");
    } else {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("_");
    }
  }

  // Print initial blanks in console
  console.log(blanksAndSuccesses);

  // Reprint the guessesLeft to 15
  document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = "Number of Guesses: " + numGuesses;

  // Prints blanks at beginning of each round in HTML
  document.getElementById("wordToGuess").innerHTML = blanksAndSuccesses.join(" ");

  // Clears wrong guesses from previous round
  document.getElementById("wrong-guesses").innerHTML = "Wrong Guesses: " + wrongGuesses.join(" ");
}

// checkLetters() function - holds all comparisons for matches
function checkLetters(letter) {

  // Boolean will be toggled based on if user's letter is found anywhere in the word
  var letterInWord = false;

  // Checks if letter exists inside the array at all
  for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {

    if (selectedWord[i] === letter) {

      // If letter exists, then toggle boolean to true, used in next step
      letterInWord = true;
    }
  }

  // If letter exists somewhere in word, figure out exactly where (which indices)
  if (letterInWord) {

    // Loop through the word
    for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {

      // Populate blanksAndSuccesses with every instance of the letter
      if (selectedWord[i] === letter) {

        // Set specific blank space(s) to equal correct letter when there is a match
        blanksAndSuccesses[i] = letter;
      }
    }

    // Log current blanks and successes for testing
    console.log(blanksAndSuccesses);
  }

  // If letter doesn't exist at all...
  else {

    // Add letter to list of wrong letters
    wrongGuesses.push(letter);

    // Also subtract one of the guesses
    numGuesses--;

  }

}

// roundComplete() function - will run necessary code after each guess is made
function roundComplete() {

  // Log initial status in console re: how many wins, losses, and guesses are left
  console.log("Win Count: " + winCounter + " | Loss Count: " + lossCounter + " | Num Guesses: " + numGuesses);

  // HTML UPDATES
  // ============

  // Update HTML to reflect new number of guesses
  document.getElementById("guesses-left").innerHTML = "Guesses Left: " + numGuesses;

  // Print array of guesses and blanks onto page
  document.getElementById("wordToGuess").innerHTML = blanksAndSuccesses.join(" ");

  // Print wrong guesses to page
  document.getElementById("wrong-guesses").innerHTML = "Wrong Guesses: " + wrongGuesses.join(" ");

  // If word guess string equals solution
  if (lettersInWord.toString() === blanksAndSuccesses.toString()) {

    // Add to the win counter
    winCounter++;

    // Give user "win" alert
    alert("You Win!");

    // Update win counter in HTML
    document.getElementById("win-counter").innerHTML = "Wins: " + winCounter;

    // Restart game
    startGame();
  }

  // if user has run out of guesses
  else if (numGuesses === 0) {
    // Add to loss counter
    lossCounter++;

    // Give user "lose" alert
    alert("You Lose!");

    // Update loss counter in HTML
    document.getElementById("loss-counter").innerHTML = "Losses: " + lossCounter;

    // Restart game
    startGame();

  }

}

// MAIN PROCESS
// =======================================================

// Starts game
startGame();

// Then initiates function for capturing key clicks
document.onkeyup = function (event) {

  // captures keypress, eliminating repeat letters
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    letterGuessed = event.key;

    if (wrongGuesses.indexOf(letterGuessed) !== -1) {
      alert("You already guessed that letter.");
      return;
    }

    // Runs code to check for correct guesses
    checkLetters(letterGuessed);

    // Runs code that ends each round
    roundComplete();

  }

};

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What is `numBlanks`? It doesn't come as a surprise that it's the number of blanks. However it is never updated in the provided code sample. Can I conclude that `numBlanks` is therefore always the size of the full word `selectedWord`? If not you might have a problem with your *for* loops.

Comment: I feel like there is move code that you have not included...Can we see the rest?

Comment: I'll re-update.  I had left out the HTML updates since that wasn't causing an issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a mix of my code and code from the website listed below, I have solved my issue.  Thank you to those who offered help.  I learned a lot!

```
<a link='https://codepen.io/cathydutton/pen/ldazc?editors=1010'></a>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can just check if the event's keyCode is in the Array with by checking if its `index` in the Array is -1 (not in the Array).

```
document.onkeyup = function (event) {
   var letterGuessed;
  // captures keypress, eliminating repeat letters
  if (event.keyCode >= 65 && event.keyCode <= 90) {
    letterGuessed = event.key;

    if(wrongGuesses.indexOf(letterGuessed)!==-1){
        alert("You already guessed that letter.");
        return;
    }      

  // Runs code to check for correct guesses
  checkLetters(letterGuessed);

  // Runs code that ends each round
  roundComplete();

}
```

Comment: I'm not having issues with it registering, though your code is shorter and more efficient than mine.  The problem is that, after a few wrong guesses, even when the correct letters are guessed, sometimes it will register the win and sometimes it just sits there and requires a refresh to play again.

Answer (score 0):

You are having an issue in the place where you are inserting the asterisk, while you are inserting it to the blanksAndSuccess String, you are never removing it when you are comparing it with the random word.

```
for (var i = 0; i < numBlanks; i++) {
    if (lettersInWord[i] === " ") {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("*");
    } else {
      blanksAndSuccesses.push("_");
    }
  }
```

Add this where you are doing the compare

```
 if (lettersInWord.toString() === blanksAndSuccesses.toString().replace("*", " ")) {
```

This should help start the game properly.

Comment: I would really like to try your solution, but I'm unclear as to where it belongs.  Can you give me a little more information?  I'm still new to learning my logic and how to puzzle things out.  Thank you!

Comment: you have to replace your line no 191 with the if statement that I have sent " if (lettersInWord.toString() === blanksAndSuccesses.toString().replace("*", " ")) { "

Comment: @DesireeF. the first snippet is why its causing the issue. you dont have to replace that. the second one with the if condition is the fix

Comment: Thank you!  I appreciate the help.

Comment: @DesireeF. Did it fix the issue?

Comment: It didn't.  I reposted my new question because the only solution to the original problem was to remove the spaces within the array answers - "bon jovi" being "bonjovi", etc.  I'll probably just have to leave it that way.  I was making it a portfolio piece.  I truly appreciate your help!